# Why must C++ function parameter packs be placeholders or pack expansions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++20

The declarator for a C++20 function parameter pack must either be a [placeholder](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#18) or a [pack expansion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#21).  For example:

```
// OK, template parameter pack only, no function parameter pack
template<unsigned ...I> void good1() {}

// OK function parameter pack is pack expansion of decltype(I)
template<unsigned ...I> void good2(decltype(I)...i) {}

// OK contains placeholder auto
void good3(std::same_as<unsigned> auto...i) {}

// OK contains placeholder auto
void good4(std::convertible_to<unsigned> auto...i) {}

// Error, no pack expansion or placeholder
template<unsigned = 0> void bad(unsigned...i) {}
```

This seems to make it impossible to declare a function that takes a variable number of parameters of a specific type.  Of course, `good2` above will do it, but you have to specify some number of dummy template arguments, as in `good2<0,0,0>(1,2,3)`.  `good3` sort of does it, except if you call `good3(1,2,3)` it will fail and you have to write `good3(1U,2U,3U)`.  I'd like a function that works when you say `good(1, 2U, '\003')`--basically as if you had an infinite number of overloaded functions `good()`, `good(unsigned)`, `good(unsigned, unsigned)`, etc.

`good4` will work, except now the arguments aren't actually of type `unsigned`, which could be a problem depending on context.  Specifically, it could lead to extra `std::string` copies in a function like this:

```
void do_strings(std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto...s) {}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I missing some trick that would allow one to write a function that takes a variable number of arguments of a specific type?  (I guess the one exception is C strings, because you can make the length a parameter pack as in `template<std::size_t...N> void do_cstrings(const char(&...s)[N]) {/*...*/}`, but I want to do this for a type like std::size_t)
2. Why does the standard impose this restriction?

**update**

康桓瑋 asked why not use `good4` in conjunction with forwarding references to avoid extra copies.  I agree that `good4` is the closest to what I want to do, but there are some annoyances with the fact that the parameters are different types, and some places where references do not work, either.  For example, say you write code like this:

```
void
good4(std::convertible_to<unsigned> auto&&...i)
{
  for (auto n : {i...})
    std::cout << n << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You test it with `good(1, 2, 3)` and it seems to work.  Then later someone uses your code and writes `good(1, 2, sizeof(X))` and it fails with a confusing compiler error message.  Of course, the answer was to write `for (auto n : {unsigned(i)...})`, which in this case is fine, but there might be other cases where you use the pack multiple times and the conversion operator is non-trivial and you only want to invoke it once.

Another annoying problem arises if your type has a constexpr conversion function that doesn't touch `this`, because in that case the function won't work on a forwarding reference.  Admittedly this is highly contrived, but imagine the following program that prints "11":

```
template<std::size_t N> std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> cnst = {};

constexpr std::tuple tpl ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');

inline const char *
stringify(std::convertible_to<decltype(cnst<1>)> auto...i)
{
  static constexpr const char str[] = { get<i>(tpl)..., '\0' };
  return str;
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << stringify(cnst<1>, cnst<1>) << std::endl;
}
```

If you change the argument to `stringify` to a forwarding reference `stringify(std::convertible_to<decltype(cnst<1>)> auto&&...i)`, it will fail to compile because of [this](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/973).

**update2**

Here's a more comprehensive example showing why `good4` isn't quite good enough if you want to avoid extra moves/copies:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <concepts>

struct Tracer {
  Tracer() { std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl; }
  Tracer(int) { std::cout << "int constructed" << std::endl; }
  Tracer(const Tracer &) { std::cout << "copy constructed" << std::endl; }
  Tracer(Tracer &&) { std::cout << "move constructed" << std::endl; }
  void do_something() const {}
};

void
f1(Tracer t1, Tracer t2, Tracer t3)
{
  t1.do_something();
  t2.do_something();
  t3.do_something();
}

void
f2(std::convertible_to<Tracer> auto ...ts)
{
  (Tracer{ts}.do_something(), ...); // binary fold over comma
}

void
f3(std::convertible_to<Tracer> auto&& ...ts)
{
  (Tracer{std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)}.do_something(), ...);
}

void
f4(std::initializer_list<Tracer> tl)
{
  for (const auto &t : tl)
    t.do_something();
}

void
f5(std::convertible_to<Tracer> auto&& ...ts)
{
  std::initializer_list<Tracer> tl { std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)... };
  for (const auto &t : tl)
    t.do_something();
}

int
main()
{
  Tracer t;
  std::cout << "=== f1(t, 0, {}) ===" << std::endl;
  f1(t, 0, {});
  std::cout << "=== f2(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===" << std::endl;
  f2(t, 0, Tracer{});
  std::cout << "=== f3(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===" << std::endl;
  f3(t, 0, Tracer{});
  std::cout << "=== f4({t, 0, {}}) ===" << std::endl;
  f4({t, 0, {}});
  std::cout << "=== f5(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===" << std::endl;
  f5(t, 0, Tracer{});
  std::cout << "=== done ===" << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
default constructed
=== f1(t, 0, {}) ===
default constructed
int constructed
copy constructed
=== f2(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===
default constructed
copy constructed
copy constructed
int constructed
copy constructed
=== f3(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===
default constructed
copy constructed
int constructed
move constructed
=== f4({t, 0, {}}) ===
copy constructed
int constructed
default constructed
=== f5(t, 0, Tracer{}) ===
default constructed
copy constructed
int constructed
move constructed
=== done ===
```

We are trying to replicate an inifinite sequence of overloaded functions that behave like `f1`, which is what the rejected P1219R2 would have given us.  Unfortunately, the only approach that doesn't require an extra copy is to take a `std::initializer_list<Tracer>`, which requires an extra set of braces on function invocation.

Comment: I think `good4` can meet your needs. I don't see any examples of it making an extra copy if you declare it as `void do_strings(convertible_to<string_view> auto const&...)`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I updated my answer to include an example.  If you expand the parameter pack multiple times with a conversion operator `mytype(i)...`, and the conversion to `mytype` is non-trivial or side effects, then this is not the same as just expanding the parameter pack `i...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does the standard impose this restriction?

I'll focus on the "why's", as other answer already visits various workarounds.

[P1219R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1219r2.html) (*Homogeneous variadic function parameters*) went as far as EWG

> ```
> # EWG incubator: in favor
> SF F N A SA
> 5  2 3 0 0
> ```

But [was eventually rejected](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/297) for C++23 by EWG

> ```
> SF F N A SA
> 2  8 8 9 2
> ```

I think the rationale was that whilst the proposal was very well-written the actual language facility was not an essentially useful one, and particularly not enough to hold its weight given that it's a breaking change due to the C varargs comma mess:

> The varargs ellipsis was originally introduced in C++ along with function prototypes. At that time, the feature did not permit a comma prior to the ellipsis. When C later adopted these features, the syntax was altered to require the intervening comma, emphasizing the distinction between the last formal parameter and the varargs parameters. To retain compatibility with C, the C++ syntax was modified to permit the user to add the intervening comma. Users therefore can choose to provide the comma or leave it out.
>
> When paired with function parameter packs, this creates a syntactic ambiguity that is currently resolved via a disambiguation rule: When an ellipsis that appears in a function parameter list might be part of an abstract (nameless) declarator, it is treated as a pack declaration if the parameter's type names an unexpanded parameter pack or contains auto; otherwise, it is a varargs ellipsis. At present, this rule effectively disambiguates in favor of a parameter pack whenever doing so produces a well-formed result.
>
> Example (status quo):
>
> ```
> template <class... T>
> void f(T...); // declares a variadic function template with a function parameter pack
>
> template <class T>
> void f(T...); // same as void f(T, ...)
> ```
>
> With homogeneous function parameter packs, **this disambiguation rule
> needs to be revisited**. It would be very natural to interpret the
> second declaration above as a function template with a homogeneous
> function parameter pack, and that is the resolution proposed here. By
> requiring a comma between a parameter list and a varargs ellipsis, the
> disambiguation rule can be dropped entirely, simplifying the language
> without losing any functionality or degrading compatibility with C.
>
> **This is a breaking change**, but likely not a very impactful one. [...]

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the standard impose this restriction?

Most likely because this would confuse(or create complications) users with the old **C varargs function** that have almost same syntax(with unnamed parameter) as shown below:

```
//this is a C varargs function
void good3(int...) 
           ^^^^^^
{
    
}
```

Now if the fourth function `bad` was allowed:

```
 
template<int = 0> void bad(int...i)
                           ^^^^^^^ --->this is very likely to confuse users as some may consider it as a C varargs function instead of a function parameter pack 
{
}
```

IMO the above seems atleast a little ambiguous due to the similarity in the syntax of C varargs and a function parameter pack.

From [dcl.fct#22](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#22):

> There is a **syntactic ambiguity** when an ellipsis occurs at the end of a parameter-declaration-clause without a preceding comma.
> In this case, the ellipsis is parsed as part of the abstract-declarator if the type of the parameter either names a template parameter pack that has not been expanded or contains auto; otherwise, it is parsed as part of the parameter-declaration-clause.

---

> I'd like a function that works when you say good(1, 2U, '\003')

You can use `std::common_type` for this.

```
template <typename... T, typename l= std::common_type_t<T...>>
void func(T&&... args) {
}
```

---

> Am I missing some trick that would **allow one to write a function that takes a variable number of arguments of a specific type**?

The `good3` given in your example is very readable and should be used from C++20. Though if one is using C++17 then one way to do this is using the SFINAE principle with a combination of `std::conjunction` and `std::is_same` as shown below.

##### Method 1

Here we simply check if all the arguments passed are of the same type.

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Args>...>, bool>
func(const T & first, const Args & ... args)
{
    std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    func(4,5,8);    //works
    //func(4,7.7); //wont work as types are different
    std::string s1 = "a", s2 = "b"; 
    func(s1, s2);  //works
    //func(s1, 2);   //won't work as types are different
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mJYl49QIwAg0KVYU)

---

Looking at your comment it seems you want to add one more restriction that the program should work only when

a) all the arguments are of the same type

b) all of those matches a specific type say `int`, or `std::string`.

This can be done by adding a `static_assert` inside the function template:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>, "Even though all parameters are of the same type, they are not int");
```

##### Method 2

Here use the `static_assert` shown above to check if the arguments passes are of a specific type like `int`.

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Args>...>, bool>
func(const T & first, const Args & ... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>, "Even though all parameters are of the same type, they are not int");
    std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    func(3,3);    //works
    //func(4,7.7); //wont work as types are different
    std::string s1 = "a", s2 = "b"; 
    //func(s1, s2);  //won't work as even though they are of the same type but not int type
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xKtfVoRdvtc15uTc)

---

Comment: Sorry, what I want to do is write a function that takes one specific type, not a function in which all the arguments are the same type.  So in your example, `func` is not what I want, because it accepts both ints and strings.  Show me, for example, a function that is the equivalent of the infinite set of overloads func(), func(string_view), func(string_view, string_view), etc.

Comment: @user3188445 This is what i showed. The function `func` takes arguments of only one specific type. For example, it could either accept all `int`s or all `std::string`'s but not a combination of both. If you want to even restrict it more you can add a `static_assert` inside the function template checking if `T` is the same as say an `int` or `size_t` etc. See [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xKtfVoRdvtc15uTc).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's needs, OP wants `func(4,5,8U)` to still work, but the argument types are deduced as `unsigned`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't see an example given by OP in the original question that says that says `func(4,5,8U)` should work. Instead OP gave example `good3(1U,2U,3U)` and `good3(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Your answer is basically functionally equivalent to the OP's `good3` (which is not what the OP wanted), except you're using ugly C++17 SFINAE.

Comment: @康桓瑋  Re:I have added some explanation which explains why the standard might impose such restriction as asked in OP's second part of the question. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: This is a *language-lawyer* tag question, and you should try to explain it more from a language perspective than from your own opinion. Also, since you've explained that it's not possible, what's the point of coming up with a C++17 answer that's basically equivalent to the OP's `good3`?

Comment: I think there is partial support for your explanation in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct#22 but it still doesn't make sense to me, because you can always just add a dummy variable name at the end if you need to.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I'm not asking for `void f(int...i)`, I'm asking for `template<int dummy = 0> void f(int...i)`, so the the standard could say that the varargs parsing only applies to either non-template functions, or maybe extern "C" functions (since it wouldn't be hard to change C++ includes to have a comma before the ellipsis in old-style varargs functions).

Comment: @user3188445 Yes, i got that you were talking about the `template<int dummy = 0> void f(int...i)` and not just `void f(int...i)`. But i see one problem here which is that function templates are not actually functions they are recipes for generating functions. So imposing the restriction that you proposed(which is as follows) *" the standard could say that the varargs parsing only applies to either non-template functions"* doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @user3188445 You can make `good(1, 2U, '\003');` works by using `std::common_type`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h6nP4qvjb). I have added the same in my answer.

Comment: No, that code doesn't do the right thing, either.  The problem is that I want a specific type.  I don't want the compiler to infer the type.  Imagine overloaded functions `f()`, `f(string_view)`, `f(string_view, string_view)`, `f(string_view,string_view,string_view)`, etc.  The question is how to write a template function that behaves identically to those overloaded functions no matter what the types passed in--not just does it compile, but does it invoke conversion functions, and is the arg pack all of type `string_view`.

Comment: @user3188445 I don't think it is possible because using "implicit conversions" during TAD isn't allowed by the standard.

Comment: Exactly! Another way to phrase my question is how to create varargs functions that effectively don't do TAD.  (You can sort of do it with string literals because of the length inference.)  So why didn't the C++ committee allow some way to have arg packs without TAD?  I mean especially given that `decltype(I)...i` works for capture, why not allow some way to do that without having to type angle brackets as in `good2`?

Comment: @user3188445 I agree that `template<unsigned ...I> void good2(I...i) {}` would've been much more clearer/readable. I also want this feature but then we come to the same thing that we already discussed which is that it maybe syntactically ambigious and adding a rule specifically for function templates as you suggested can potentially create even more ambiguity. Just imagine if some writes: `template<unsigned ...I> void good2(I...i) {}` and then some other person writes `template<unsigned ...I> void good2(I...) {}`, are they the same or different? Note in second case parameter is unnamed.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing some trick that would allow one to write a function that takes a variable number of arguments of a specific type?

If I understand the question correctly, you can work around it by adding a proxy function that casts and forwards arguments to actual implementation:

```
unsigned wrap_sum(auto&&...args) {
  return []<std::size_t...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>,
                             std::conditional_t<true, unsigned, decltype(I)> ... args) {

    return (0u + ... + args);

  }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{},
    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: I agree that once you are willing to use forwarding references, you can solve the problem (albeit inelegantly).  It's not identical to what I want, in that there are cases where you can no longer access `constexpr` methods of the arguments at compile time.  It just seems needlessly complex to do something simple, all because of the need for backwards compatibility with a weird technicality that C lets you can omit the last comma in varargs functions, even in cases where the C++ code isn't valid C and it would be fine to require the extra comma (or conversely require a parameter name).

Comment: @user3188445 *where you can no longer access constexpr methods of the arguments at compile time.*     This is incorrect. see https://godbolt.org/z/8q3n3WW4v

Comment: Sure, that works in this case, but in other cases would lead to a gratuitous copy.  I mean I guess the high-level point is that for any given type, there's an idiom that works, but there's no idiom that will do exactly what I want for every single type.

Comment: @user3188445 I don't think this can do more copying than separative non-templated overloaded functions, I can be wrong though. Can you give an example?  If you're talking about that there's one nested lambda(and its static variable) for every outer function, you can move out the lambda and change it to a regular function template.

Comment: @user3188445 Sorry I cannot understand *there's no idiom that will do exactly what I want for every single type*, doesn't this answer what current question asks? Maybe you should elaborated exactly what you want (and maybe it's a new question). I might be missing something though.

Comment: In other words, if I want a function equivalent to the (non-C++) `f(const std::string&...s)`, then I should use the equivalent of `good4`, and I'll avoid any copies.  If I want `f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>...i)` then I should use the construction you suggested in godbolt.org/z/8q3n3WW4v .  The fact that the code for passing by reference is so different from the code for passing by value leads me to conclude that these are essentially two different idioms.

Comment: @user3188445 You can use `std::conditional_t<true, T, decltype(I)>` with any specified type `T`, e.g. `T=const std::string&` for your `f(const std::string&...s)`.